# uptart and gnokii and chroot

Tags: upstart, chroot

I try to run this upstart script.

```
#
description     ""
author          "" 

start on runlevel [2345]
 stop on runlevel [!2345]

#chroot /home/ubuntu/

respawn
respawn limit 1 1
exec sudo smsd -u cable -p akses -d cab -c localhost -m mysql -b SM -f     /var/log/smsdaemon.log
```

but smsd used to find configuration in my home folder.
and when I uncomment chroot(where is config) part it fails:

```
start: Job failed to start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I just needed to export my home folder.

```
env HOME=/home/ubuntu/
export HOME
```

And it finds configuration.